# Python things which are neither True nor False

Tags: python, boolean

I just found this :

```
a = (None,)
print (a is True)
print (a is False)
print (a == True)
print (a == False)
print (a == None)
print (a is None)
if a : print "hello"
if not a : print "goodbye"
```

which produces :

```
False
False
False
False
False
False
hello
```

So a neither is, nor equals True nor False, but acts as True in an if statement.

Why?

Update :

actually, I've just realized that this isn't as obscure as I thought. I get the same result for a=2, as well (though not for a=0 or a=1, which are considered equal to False and True respectively)

Comment: Did you read http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing?  What was ambiguous or confusing there?

Comment: Probably the best evidence yet why tests of "is True/False" or "== True/False" are a Bad Idea in Python.  Don't do them!  Adopt the idiom where a value is evaluated for its boolean-ness, as if you explicitly called bool(var).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25329937/974555

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`a` is a one-member tuple, which evaluates to `True`. `is` test identity of the object, therefore, you get `False` in all those test. `==` test equality of the objects, therefore, you get `False` again.

in `if` statement a `__bool__` (or `__nonzero__`) used to evaluate the object, for a non-empty tuple it should return `True`, therefore you get `True`. hope that answers your question.

**edit**: the reason `True` and `False` are equal to `1` and `0` respectively is because  `bool` type implemented as a subclass of `int` type.

Comment: Actually, there's a clearer statement on the 1, 0 thing in http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing.  It's a matter of definition of the `bool` function, not a coincidence of implementation.

Comment: @S.Lott: hm, http://docs.python.org/3.1/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__ says that `__bool__` can only return boolean values.

Answer (score 13):

I find almost all the explanations here unhelpful, so here is another try:

The confusion here is based on that testing with "is", "==" and "if" are three different things.

- "is" tests identity, that is, if it's the same object. That is obviously not true in this case.
- "==" tests value equality, and obviously the only built in objects with the values of True and False are the object True and False (with the exception of the numbers 0 and 1, of any numeric type).

And here comes the important part:

- 'if' tests on boolean values. That means that whatever expression you give it, it will be converted to either True or False. You can make the same with bool(). And bool((None,)) will return True. The things that will evaluate to False is listed in the docs (linked to by others here)

Now maybe this is only more clear in my head, but at least I tried. :)

Answer (score 2):

Things in python don't have to be one of `True` or `False`.

When they're used as a text expression for `if`/`while` loops, they're converted to booleans. You can't use `is` or `==` to test what they evaluate to. You use `bool( thing )`

```
>>> a = (None,)
>>> bool(a)
True
```

Also note:

```
>>> 10 == True
False
>>> 10 is True
False
>>> bool(10)
True
```

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR:

`if` and `==` are completely different operations. The `if` checks the truth value of a variable while `==` compares two variables. `is` also compares two variables but it compares if both reference the same object.

So it makes no sense to compare a variable with `True`, `False` or `None` to check it's truth value.

### What happens when `if` is used on a variable?

In Python a check like `if` implicitly gets the `bool` of the argument. So

```
if something:
```

will be (under the hood) executed like:

```
if bool(something):
```

Note that you should never use the latter in your code because it's considered less pythonic and it's slower (because Python then uses two `bool`s: `bool(bool(something))`). **Always use the `if something`.**

If you're interested in how it's evaluated by CPython 3.6:

[image]

Note that CPython doesn't exactly use `hasattr` here. It does check if the `type` of `x` implements the method but without going through the `__getattribute__` method (`hasattr` would use that).

In Python2 the method was called `__nonzero__` and not `__bool__`

### What happens when variables are compared using `==`?

The `==` will check for equality (often also called "value equality"). However this equality check doesn't coerce the operands (unlike in other programming languages). The value equality in Python is explicitly implemented. So you can do:

```
>>> 1 == True  # because bool subclasses int, True is equal to 1 (and False to 0)
True

>>> 1.0 == True  # because float implements __eq__ with int
True

>>> 1+1j == True  # because complex implements __eq__ with int
True
```

However `==` will default to reference comparison (`is`) if the comparison isn't implemented by either operand. That's why:

```
>>> (None, ) == True
False
```

Because `tuple` doesn't "support" equality with `int` and vise-versa. Note that even comparing lists to tuples is "unsupported":

```
>>> [None] == (None, )
False
```

Just in case you're interested this is how CPython (3.6) implements equality (the orange arrows indicate if an operation returned the `NotImplemented` constant):

[image]

That's only roughly correct because CPython also checks if the `type()` of `value1` or `value2` implements `__eq__` (without going through the `__getattribute__` method!) before it's called (if it exists) or skipped (if it doesn't exist).

Note that the behavior in Python2 was significantly more lengthy (at least if the methods returned `NotImplemented`) and Python 2 also supported `__cmp__`,

### What happens when variables are compared using `is`?

`is` is generally referred to as reference equality comparison operator. It only returns `True` if both variables refer to *exactly the same object*. In general variables that hold the same value can nevertheless refer to different objects:

```
>>> 1 is 1.  # same value, different types
False

>>> a = 500
>>> a is 500  # same value, same type, different instances
False
```

Note that CPython uses cached values, so sometimes variables that "should" be different instances are actually the same instance. That's why I didn't use `500 is 500` (literals with the same value in the same line are always equal) and why I couldn't use `1` as example (because CPython re-uses the values -5 to 256).

But back to your comparisons: `is` compares references, that means it's not enough if both operands have the same type and value but they have to be the same reference. Given that they didn't even have the same type (you're comparing `tuple` with `bool` and `NoneType` objects) it's impossible that `is` would return `True`.

Note that `True`, `False` and `None` (and also `NotImplemented` and `Ellipsis`) are constants and singletons in CPython. That's not just an optimization in these cases.

Answer (score 1):

(None,) is a tuple that contains an element, it's not empty and therefore does not evaluate to False in that context.

Answer (score 1):

Because `a=(None,)` is a tuple containing a single element `None`

Try again with `a=None` and you will see there is a different result.

Also try `a=()` which is the empty tuple. This has a truth value of false

Answer (score 0):

In Python every type can be converted to `bool` by using the `bool()` function or the [`__nonzero__` method](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__).

Examples:

- Sequences (lists, strings, ...) are converted to `False` when they are empty.
- Integers are converted to `False` when they are equal to 0.
- You can define this behavior in your own classes by overriding `__nonzero__()`.

[Edit]

In your code, the tuple `(None,)` is converted using `bool()` in the `if` statements. Since it's non-empty, it evaluates to `True`.